# QoS policy not limiting bandwidth

Tags: networking, qos

I try to test QoS bandwidth limitation with Win10 x64. First I wrote some code which posts large http-packets to localhost and limit bandwidth for this app by its process name. Limitation did not work, because posting was still happening at fast rate and with resource monitor I inspected really high upload rate. I could not limit bandwidth neither by process name nor by url mask. So I decided that maybe all of this is not working due to sending to locahost. So i just tried to limit bandwidth of chrome.exe processes by its name to 1 kbit/s and chrome was still working perfectly.

Question is, why bandwidth limitations not working neither for custom app nor for chrome.exe? And as for custom app - should it actually work if I send packets to localhost? I need a way to be able to check QoS policy working using just one physical machine.

gpedit.msc) my QoS policy with tcp/udp, 1 kbit/s bandwidth limitation, any port and DCSP value of 10:

[image]

(resource monitor) chrome.exe processes upload rates above 1 kbit/s (=128 byte/s):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this? : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2733528/policy-based-qos-not-working-in-windows-7-clients

Resolution
If you need to DSCP values to take effect on the adapter which does not have Domain access, you need to add the following registry on the system:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\QoS

Type: REG_SZ

Name: Do not use NLA

Value: 1

Create key "QoS" if it does not exist.

After you create the above registry key, you need to reboot the computer.

I think it has helped me get those limits to register in the past and it also gets reset every patch or so!

Also I don't use DSCP values but I have a specific .exe target on both udp tcp

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your effort in providing the answer, but link-only answer is not a good answer, because if the link is broken, moved, or content changed, your answer will be invalidated and may need to be removed. Instead, please put a summary of the content inside the link on your answer. Thank you and have a nice day!